# Spring Boot - Quartz Scheduler - Retrieve all jobs details

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance, quartz-scheduler

I am using below code to get the all Job Details and display them in my UI. But it is taking too long ( Around 35 seconds )  to fetch the job details ( around 150 Quartz jobs ) from QUARTZ using JDBC data store ( Oracle DB).

1. Is there any alternate ways to speed up the task?
2. Any API support available for pagination from Quartz?

```
//All below code can be written using Java 8 Streams as well. Broke down the code to understand which //operation is taking time

Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();

Set<TriggerKey> triggerKeys = scheduler.getTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher.triggerGroupEquals(groupName)); //groupName - my group name - filtering by groupname

Iterator iterator = triggerKeys .iterator();


//This while block is taking around 12 seconds for around 150 jobs
while(iterator.hasNext()){
TriggerKey triggerKey = (TriggerKey) iterator.next();
if(scheduler.getTriggerState(triggerKey).equals(TriggerState.NONE)){
    iterator.remove();
}

Map<TriggerKey, MyPOJO> myJobMap = new HashMap();

//This for loop is taking around 22 seconds for around 150 jobs
for(TriggerKey key : triggerKeys){

Trigger trigger = scheduler.getTrigger(key);

JobDataMap jobDataMap = scheduler.getJobDetail(trigger.getJobKey()).getJobDataMap();

MyPOJO myPOJO = jobDataMap.get("MYJOBPOJO");

myJobMap.put(key, myPOJO);

}
```

I have gone through the Quartz documentation but did not find any specific details on how to improve this read operation performance

Comment: If they are in the database why not just write a query which would return just the data you need? Instead of trying to do this through the Quartz API?